Writing to unavailable hard disk on ubuntu using C# blocks for minutes before throwing error
I need to detect on an Ubuntu system whether a hard disk can be written to.
I run the following code once per second, and then I proceed to disconnect the hard disk drives from the motherboard.
Eventually an I/O Error, or read-only file system exception is thrown, but it can take minutes until it does which is too late for my use case.
What could be the problem?
    private bool IsWriteable()
    {
        try
        {
           
            using (var file = _fileSystem.File.Open(_testFilePath, new FileStreamOptions
                   {
                       Mode = FileMode.Create,
                       Access = FileAccess.Write,
                       Options = FileOptions.WriteThrough,
                       BufferSize = 0
                   }))
            {
                file.Write(new byte[4096]);
                file.Flush();
            }
            
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            
            return false;
        }
    }




Write it so you can "time" the operations ... detecting the equivalent of a "timeout".  Which means knowing how long an operation "should" take.
